# Cannot pass where Params to query with Twig variable

Tags: query, elementquery, custom

I have a text field that has three values on new lines.

```
E01001667
E01001668
E01000779
```

I want to use these for a query that looks like this:

```
{% set mylsoas =  craft.entries.
section('imdData')
.orWhere(['in', 'content.field_lsoacode', ['E01001667','E01001668','E01000779']])
.all() %}
```

The above query works and returns the records I want when i add the values directly.
However I need to build the where params dynamically from the text field values so I am doing this:

```
{%  set lsoas = uentry.selectedLsoas | split("\n") %}
{% set whereParams = null %}
{# trim and join #}
{% for ons in lsoas %}
    {%  set whereParams = whereParams ~ "'"~ons~"'," %}
{% endfor %}
{% set whereParams = "[" ~ whereParams|trim(',', 'right') ~ "]" %}
```

The output of whereParams on screen works in the query and give me this:

```
{{ whereParams }}
outputs: ['E01001667','E01001668','E01000779']
```

But when i pass the variable in to the query i get a zero results - no errors.

```
{% set mylsoas =  craft.entries.
section('imdData')
.orWhere(['in', 'content.field_lsoacode', whereParams])
.all() %}
```

At a loss to get this working.
Any ideas welcome:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing the issue is that your `whereParams` variable is actually a string, brackets and all – not an array. So, you'll just need to make sure that it's an actual array instead.

The good news is that you're quite close, just by doing `{% set lsoas = uentry.selectedLsoas | split("\n") %}` – at that point the `lsoas` variable is actually an array already, so in theory you should just be able to use that variable as the `whereParams` directly.

Something like this should work – note the `|filter` appended after the `|split`, this will remove any empty values from the array, and the `|map(ons => ons|trim)` part removes leading/trailing whitespace from each value:

```
{% set lsoas = uentry.selectedLsoas | split("\n") | filter | map(ons => ons|trim) %}

{% set mylsoas =  craft.entries
    .section('imdData')
    .orWhere(['in', 'content.field_lsoacode', lsoas])
    .all() %}
```

Finally, I'm not sure why you need to use `orWhere()` (or simply `where()`) in this case – you can probably just do this, which is a lot simpler:

```
{% set mylsoas =  craft.entries
    .section('imdData')
    .lsoacode(lsoas)
    .all() %}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. I thought i was overcomplicating it - you are right, i didn't need where() at all.

Answer (score 3):

You may be overthinking this! It's pretty rare that you'll need to reach directly for the ActiveQuery `where`, `orWhere`, and `andWhere` methods—unless I've misunderstood what kind of results you're going for.

> There are couple unrelated issues with the sample code that I think are worth addressing, but we're going to sidestep them with the solution.
>
> Broadly, though, it looks like what you're trying to do is replicate Twig *syntax* (`"['one', 'two', 'three']"`), rather than build up an *array* (`['one', 'two', three']`).
>
> Documentation for `.where()`, describing the [range of formats for conditions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail).

That said, **Craft automatically provides some convenience methods for working with fields**. In your case, I think the default behavior is enough to produce the desired results:

```
{% set mylsoas =  craft
  .entries()
  .section('imdData')
  .lsoacode(['E01001667', 'E01001668', 'E01000779'])
  .all() %}
```

This will produce an `andWhere()` SQL condition like `content.field_lsoacode IN ('E01001667', 'E01001668', 'E01000779')`.

So, if you need to parameterize this:

```
{# Template: main.twig #}
{% set lsoas = uentry.selectedLsoas | split("\n") %}

{{ include('lsoa-list', {
  codes: lsoas,
}) }}

{# Template: lsoa-list.twig #}

{% set mylsoas =  craft
  .entries()
  .section('imdData')
  .lsoacode(codes)
  .all() %}
```

If you do really need the `orWhere()` syntax, then we may have to dive deeper into managing arrays in Twig, and check out [this question and Moritz's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/38471/get-array-of-titles-instead-of-whole-collection-of-entries-attributes) about how to dynamically build queries now that field column handles include a randomized suffix.

The same parameterization seems like it'd still work, though, in this context…

```
{# Template: main.twig #}
{% set lsoas = uentry.selectedLsoas | split("\n") %}

{{ include('lsoa-list', {
  codes: lsoas,
}) }}

{# Template: lsoa-list.twig #}

{% set mylsoas =  craft
  .entries()
  .section('imdData')
  .orWhere(['in', 'content.field_lsoacode', codes])
  .all() %}
```

…because `codes` is already an array in the `in` operator format expected by `where()`.

Just to reiterate—unless there's something *really* special about to your query that requires direct use of `orWhere()`, I would avoid it!

Comment: Thanks for detailed response August. I was overcomplicating it -and not educated enough in the way of the twig!