# Element query for specific fields

Tags: query, elementquery

Can a return schema be specified for entry queries? I'd only like the titles instead of the whole entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change both the columns to be selected and execute queries in several ways to get the results in different formats. In this case, you want to use `select()` to select the `title` column and execute the query with `column()` to get an array of titles instead of an array of `Entry` objects.

```twig
{% set entryTitles = craft.entries()
    .select('title')
    .column()
%}
```

Check out the documentation on [Advanced Element Queries](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#advanced-element-queries) for details.

If you want to select multiple columns at once, you can use [`asArray`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#asarray) to  get an array of associative arrays instead of entry objects. Note that if you want to select custom fields (instead of native properties like `title`), you need to include both the field prefix and suffixes in the column name – see [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/38471/11705) for details.

Answer (score 5):

@MoritzLost's answer should be the accepted one. But, as an alternative approach you could also use the [`|map`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/map.html) Twig filter to "prune" the entry objects returned from a normal element query:

To create an array containing only entry titles:

```
{% set entryTitles = craft.entries.all()|map(entry => entry.title) %}
```

**Edit**: As suggested by MoritzLost in the comments, an even simpler way to retrieve an array of *single* values is by using the [`|column`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#column) filter:

```
{% set entryTitles = craft.entries.all()|column('title') %}
```

To create an array of objects containing multiple values – for example, the title *and* a custom `heading` field:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.all()|map(entry => { title: entry.title, heading: entry.heading }) %}
```

Between the two approaches, using Advanced Element Queries to only fetch the column(s) that you need will probably be a bit faster - but unless this is a massive dataset, the actual difference is likely going to be completely negligible – while the big benefit with the `|map` (or `|column`) approach over Advanced Element Queries is that you won't have to worry about custom field prefixes or suffixes.

Comment: Good caveat – note that the first example can be simplified still using the [`column` filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#column): `{% set entryTitles = craft.entries.all()|column('title') %}`

Comment: Good call about the `column` filter for single values!